# Testing for different versions of non-IE browsers

Tags: firefox, testing, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I have IETester on my Windows box to test IE6-IE8.

Do you guys recommend anything similar to test say FF2-3.6, Safari 4-5, Chrome, or other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://browserlab.adobe.com/ :

> Adobe® BrowserLab is an online hosted service that lets you test the pages of your web site across a variety of web browsers and operating systems. The service works by taking screen shots of your web pages in different browsers, and then displaying them in the BrowserLab application window.
>
> BrowserLab supports [...] Chrome 7.0/8.0 (Windows), Firefox 2.0 (Macintosh OS X, Windows), Firefox 3.0 (Macintosh OS X, Windows), Firefox 3.6 (Macintosh OS X, Windows), Firefox 4.0 (Beta 7) (Windows), Internet Explorer 6.0/7.0/8.0/9.0 (Beta) (Windows), Safari 3.0/4.0/5.0 (Macintosh OS X)

BrowserLab is part of [Adobe CS Live](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/cslive/faq/), a subscription service. However,

> When you sign up before April 30, 2011 — either by registering your CS5 product or by signing up online — you can take advantage of **one year of complimentary access** to CS Live. See the [CS Live Terms of Use](http://www.adobe.com/go/cslivetou) for more information.

Comment: just registered, this is perfect for me. Any way to test JavaScript functionality?

Comment: @Twinborn see http://www.google.com/search?q=browserlab+javascript , eg. http://forums.adobe.com/message/3244115

Comment: @Twinborn if your question is answered, you should *accept* that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is Virtual PC or virtualbox.org.

Answer (score 0):

There is [netrenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/) where you can render Browser's look IEx. (You have to give your  address)
[For safari, firefox...](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/demo)